# Unable to Install mysql-server using dnf in Ansible on CentOS

Tags: bash, ansible

I need to install mysql-server and the chosen method was using Ansible as it streamlines the process. But while installing it, I have been finding this issue which I have not been able to debug. My YAML file is:

```
- name: Install mysql-server
    dnf:
      name: mysql-server
      state: present
```

But this gives out a strange error.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "warning: /var/cache/dnf/mysql56-community-e7223972839acae4/packages/mysql-community-client-5.6.51-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891029.2032368-4612-101264433776442/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 100, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891029.2032368-4612-101264433776442/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 92, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891029.2032368-4612-101264433776442/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 41, in invoke_module
    run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_p9Z365/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1363, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_p9Z365/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1352, in main
  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_p9Z365/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1326, in run
  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_p9Z365/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1230, in ensure
  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py\", line 2275, in _get_key_for_package
    keys = dnf.crypto.retrieve(keyurl, repo)
  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/crypto.py\", line 176, in retrieve
    with dnf.util._urlopen(keyurl, repo=repo) as handle:
  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/util.py\", line 130, in _urlopen
    raise IOError(str(e))
IOError: Cannot download file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql: All mirrors were tried
", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

I can not find any result or forum regarding this. This should be straight forward. Even when I run the Ansible command using: "-vvvvv" I get the following error: `ansible-playbook -vvvvv ~/ansible/playbooks/starfish.yml`

```
TASK [Install mysql-server] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/aunzaidi/ansible/playbooks/starfish.yml:35
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: aunzaidi
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~aunzaidi && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455="` echo /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/dnf.py
<localhost> PUT /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4695ow_qhed0/tmp4jtykhs2 TO /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/ /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-kgdvjtjhvcvmedzecrzshnfzzpgijvwy ; /usr/bin/python /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "warning: /var/cache/dnf/mysql56-community-e7223972839acae4/packages/mysql-community-client-5.6.51-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 100, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 92, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/aunzaidi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1637891456.166621-4897-257063194144455/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 41, in invoke_module\n    run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 176, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_nxJSO1/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1363, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_nxJSO1/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1352, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_nxJSO1/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1326, in run\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_dnf_payload_nxJSO1/ansible_dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1230, in ensure\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py\", line 2275, in _get_key_for_package\n    keys = dnf.crypto.retrieve(keyurl, repo)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/crypto.py\", line 176, in retrieve\n    with dnf.util._urlopen(keyurl, repo=repo) as handle:\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/util.py\", line 130, in _urlopen\n    raise IOError(str(e))\nIOError: Empty mirrorlist and no basepath specified!\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

I am sharing my whole YAML "starfish.yml" file as well in case it'll be required.
[starfish.yml](https://github.com/SyedAunZaidi/Ansible/blob/master/starfish.yml). Any assistance will be appericiated.

Comment: ` Empty mirrorlist and no basepath specified!\`  error is here you didn't setup your sources of mirrorlists correctly or permissions to access the lists are not setup properly ; I hope this is the source of error *I am not sure*

Comment: This is not an Ansible error. This is a problem with your system configuration. The error Ansible is receiving from the 'dnf' module gives you the info you need to debug. You should try to install the package by hand to see the output. *Automation 101: If you can't do it by hand, you can't automate it*

Comment: @0xSheepdog No, This probally isn't an issue with system configration because I was able to run this individually and I have been able to resolve this by using yum instead of dnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this only by changing package manager from dnf to yum. I am not sure why this has been creating problem as I have used the same script before on CentOS 7.9. Anyhow, I changed it by implementing following code:

```
- name: Install mysql-server
    yum:
      name: mysql-server
      state: present
```

Comment: What Distribution are you using? Is DNF not supported? That would be one reason 'dnf' module didn't work...

Comment: @0xSheepdog dnf module is working. I am using Azure VM with CentOS 7.9. I have my whole Ansible file attached. https://github.com/SyedAunZaidi/Ansible/blob/master/starfish.yml. I have absolutely no idea why dnf is working for others but not for this.

Comment: You may as well try to use the 'apt' module to install the package on CentOS7. It would work about as well as 'dnf' since neither are installed or part of a normal CentOS7 system. Maybe try using the right module for the task? Better yet, consider using the distro agnostic modules, like 'package'.